# How can I store a set of URL parameters in Java?

Tags: java

Normally I would store URL parameters (GET request parameters) with a `HashMap<String,String>` but that doesnt account for URLs like `test.php?request=id1&request=id2`. Is there any data structure implemented in Java that can deal with this (and that I can query a parameter by name)? Alternatively, is there a single class somewhere that I can use (no libraries please)?

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11733697/752527

Comment: @HanletEscaño that suffers from the exact problem that I am describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake a multimap with something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> multimap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

See the 'MultiMap' section on this page for more information:
[The Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using java to write servlet or something, as far as I know, the HttpServletRequest class comes with the parameter as a list, and for each parameter, the value is an array.

```
HttpServletRequest req=...
Enumeration<String> names=req.getParameterNames(); //
String para=names.getNextElement();//return "request"
String[] values=para.getParameterValues();// Should get["id1","id2"]
```

Now you certainly can use a list for it, like whiskeyspider suggested.

You can also make a wrapper on it before put into a hashMap,even just to serialize it. then we you need to use it, just unwrap it. But I would suggest use a list all the way, you can always just check the length to know if it is a single parameter or list.

Comment: ok, so you are saying basically the same thing as the other answer. thanks for the confirmation.