# How do we get the specific value from URL using Selenium Webdriver C#?

Tags: c#, url

My page URL is mentioned below, I want to get `JID` value.

http://.........../abc.aspx?JID=00001833

I can get complete URL from this code, but I want to get specific value.

```
string url = driver.Url;
Console.WriteLine(url);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting URL parameter in java and extract a specific text from that URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733500/getting-url-parameter-in-java-and-extract-a-specific-text-from-that-url)

Comment: I totally spaced and entered a Java dup... here's a C# one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
As JeffC suggested the proper way to get parameters you should use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

```
String yoururl = "http://example.com/abc.aspx?JID=00001833";
Uri theUri = new Uri(yoururl);
String jid = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(theUri.Query).Get("JID");
Console.WriteLine(jid);
```

Read more about `ParseQueryString` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

---

*Not recommended way (with string manipulation):

If your jid's length is fix you can do the following:*

```
string url = driver.Url;
string jid = url.Substring(url.Length-8,8)
Console.WriteLine(jid);
```

Comment: This is really not the proper way to do this. What if your JID is not 8 digits sometimes? What if there sometimes is another query parameter added to the string after the JID? See the dup I posted for the proper way to do this using `ParseQueryString()`

Answer (score 0):

**Your example redone**

```
string url = driver.Url;
string newUrl = url.Split('=').Last();
Console.WriteLine(newUrl);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this using string.Split

[DotNetFiddle Example You can run](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvTM4a)

Here is the code from within the fiddle:

```
var URL = "http://.........../abc.aspx?JID=00001833";
        var JID = URL.Split('?').Last();
        Console.WriteLine(JID);     
        var JIDVal = JID.Split('=').Last();
        Console.WriteLine(JIDVal);
```