# Parse HTTP request line in Java

Tags: java, parsing, httprequest

I would like to have generic way of parsing http request line:

`GET /foo?bar=baz HTTP/1.1`

would be parsed into object with properties: `path`, `query parameters`.

I know that I could do it manually but I wonder if there is a library for that. There is bunch od libraries parsing urls but is there any parsing http requests?

Comment: I think OP don't wants to use a whole web server library. He only asks for a library that parses the request, he wants to handle the request by himself. However I also found many topics at SO for the same question but no really satisfying answer. Depending on the complexity of your problem I would just use a simple regex with some capturing groups.
Something like `([A-Z]) /(.+) HTTP/([\d\.])` or so, probably needs some finetuning. For extracting the query parameters I think there are some nice libraries but I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11733697/2411243

Comment: @Frederik.L I don't need a http client, I just want to parse request for wiremock matcher

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was about a lib to build a request and parse the *results* of an http request.

Comment: @Frederik.L No problem, upvotes much obliged - since it would be hard to get an answer with `-1`

Comment: I have a simple library for that: https://github.com/rollback-dropdev/jrestclient There are some other libraries which do basically the same but give it a try, take a look in the examples

Comment: @rollback  I don't need a http client, I just want to parse request for wiremock matcher

Comment: @pixel This probably goes very near of what you need http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/HttpParser.htm and using a lib for parsing a line can be overkill in a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've end up with extracting `path="/foo?bar=baz"` and creating `new URL("http", "localhost", path)`