# java: get one parameter from url

Tags: java, parsing, uri, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

How can I get one specific uri parameter from an URL?
For example my url

/search?q=foo&oq=bar&aqs=chrome&client=android&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Now I want only return the q parameter (foo). My solution was to try it with a substring till indexOf & but there is a problem, if I try the same on an url without an & character.

Need to do it without a special lib, need it for kibana w/ painless.

Comment: may be this 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733500/getting-url-parameter-in-java-and-extract-a-specific-text-from-that-url`  will be useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection

Comment: thanks guys, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623364/1133346) helped me to solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623364/1133346).

Similar to my solution but `end = (end == -1 ? url.length() : end);` helped me to eliminate the remaining error.