# How to get specific characters sequences from URL / String

Tags: java, oop, url

I have a URL but i need only the value of `http_token` i.e., `somedata`
in that URL so that i can send the token value as argument in my code. How do i get it?

URL:

`https://website.com/?HTTP_TARGETPORTAL=7&HTTP_TOKEN=somedata&HSID_DOMAIN_URL=...`

Comment: One solution is to use regular expressions for this. What have you tried?

Comment: I didnt try anything can you share the code ?

Comment: No, sorry, I will not share the code. StackOverflow is for helping with specific coding issues, not a code sharing site. Please try something first, and we can help if you struggle further.

Comment: A regular expression allows you to define a pattern and try to match it. This is for example how you can verify if a given string is a valid email format (text.text@text.com). Check this website for more details: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting URL parameter in java and extract a specific text from that URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733500/getting-url-parameter-in-java-and-extract-a-specific-text-from-that-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your string to `URL` and get the query parameters.

Here is a working solution motivated from answer: [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String givenUrl = "https://healthsafeid-stage1.optum.com/protected/accountreset/password?HTTP_TARGETPORTAL=LAWW&HTTP_TARGETURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsr-smsc-stg.liveandworkwell.com%2Fservices%2Fsecure%2Fgn&HTTP_ERRORURL=https%3A%2F%2Fsr-smsc-stg.liveandworkwell.com%2Fcontent%2Fen%2Fpublic%2Ferror.html&HTTP_ACCESSTYPE=TIER1&HTTP_BRANDURL=&HTTP_LANGUAGE=en&HTTP_ACCESSCODE=12345678&HTTP_GRADIENTCOLOR1=&HTTP_GRADIENTCOLOR2=&HTTP_TOKEN=GthzXwVHL2xyAdMsHukFPGrSrP6GJHItc%2BEucuznsQk0%2FEhFrjTfr6r0fL16SKOQvus7y5dHmZ1LP3jUJtvY2w%3D%3D&HSID_DOMAIN_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fhealthsafeid-stage1.optum.com";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(givenUrl);
        Map<String, String> query_pairs = new HashMap<>();
        String query = url.getQuery();
        String[] pairs = query.split("&");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            query_pairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8").toUpperCase(), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
        }

        String httpToken = query_pairs.get("HTTP_TOKEN");
        System.out.println("Http token: " + httpToken);
    } catch (MalformedURLException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log and handle the exception
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Http token: GthzXwVHL2xyAdMsHukFPGrSrP6GJHItc%2BEucuznsQk0%2FEhFrjTfr6r0fL16SKOQvus7y5dHmZ1LP3jUJtvY2w%3D%3D
```

Advantage with this approach:

1. Not dependent on the order of the query parameters
2. Also parses other parameters. They can be stored as well if needed for future purpose.

Comment: Tried :   String params1 = "URLllllllllllllllllll";

  try {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("HTTP_TOKEN=([^&]+)");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(params1);
   while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
   }
  } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
   // error handling
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with Java regular expressions but the whole thing should be this.

I'm not sure this will work or not. There are many ways to achieve the expected result but here is the regex way.

```
String line = ""; // URL HERE
String pattern = "HTTP_TOKEN=(.+)[&]*";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("HTTP TOKEN: " + m.group(1) );
}else {
    System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
}
```

> **Regex Preview:** https://regex101.com/r/mA8bPg/2

Comment: I like your solution. a small correction would be `&`. it may or may not be present. so `[&]*` may be needed.

Comment: @SunilDabburi The regex is working fine as i tested. Correct me if i've made a mistake somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: It works for the given URL. If the token is the last key in the URL, it may not match based on your regex

Comment: @SunilDabburi Yeah, you're right.  thanks.