# How can I authenticate browser GET requests for an Express web app running on Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, csrf-token

I'm working on a web app running on firebase services. I've created an express back-end running on Firebase Cloud Functions and hosted on Firebase Hosting. I am trying to add authentication so only users with permissions can access admin pages.

I tried implementing session cookies as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies). It was successful but unfortunately was vulnerable to CSRF attacks since Cloud Functions strips all cookies without the name `__session` from incoming requests so the proposed `csrfToken` cookie solution is impossible.

I then considered using Auth's persistence in the client's local storage and sending the token in the header of a GET request. Unfortunately, I have only found tutorials on how to do this for requests within scripts e.g. for APIs, not for GET requests directly from the browser to serve a page.

It seems that there should be a simple solution. Am I missing something? Is cloud functions not meant for serving web apps like this? Is there another way to protect against CSRF without cookies? If Cloud Functions still allows the `__session` cookie is it meant to be used for storing the user's Auth Token and if so does it protect against CSRF anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the firebase Cloud Function you can implement your own Auth. However Firebase provided its own Authentication method. In the Cloud Function, it is simple use the ‘functions.auth.user().onCreate() ‘ method. You can refer to Extend Firebase Authentication with [Cloud Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-functions) for samples.

As for your GET question, are you asking about how to programmatically extract the parameter from the URL? It'ss similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733500/getting-url-parameter-in-java-and-extract-a-specific-text-from-that-url); you can pull the URL and substring the part that contain the token.