# Split a complex String object and populate values into DTO using Java

Tags: java

I have a complex  string which I  need to split two times by delimiters '&'  and '=' respectively. Then I need to set the values in Java POJO class.I need values like 2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49 to be set for requestTimestamp field in pojo, 0036 in channelResponseCode..... Like this for all fields. Due to for each all values are getting set for one field.  Please help.
My code as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String strMain = "request_timestamp=2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49&channel_response_code=0036&channel_response_desc=Payment+is+cancelled.&sub_merchant_list=";
        String arrSplit[] = strMain.split("&");
        // [request_timestamp=2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49, channel_response_code=0036, channel_response_desc=Payment+is+cancelled.,_4=, user_defined_5=, .....]
        //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrSplit));            
        Payment p = new Payment();
        for (String s : arrSplit) {
            String[] t =s.split("=");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
      if(t.length >1) {
      p.setRequest_timestamp(t[1]); 
      }
      else { p.setRequest_timestamp(""); }
     
            System.out.println("Hiii"+p.getRequest_timestamp());
      }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like URL encoding. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733500/getting-url-parameter-in-java-and-extract-a-specific-text-from-that-url

Answer (score 2):

You can use StringTokenizer for that purpose.

```
       private static final String CHANEL_RESPONSE_CODE = "channel_response_code";
private static final String CHANEL_RESPONSE_DESC = "channel_response_desc";
private static final String REQUEST_TIME_STMP = "request_timestamp";
private static final String MERCHANT_LIST = "sub_merchant_list";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String strMain = "request_timestamp=2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49&channel_response_code=0036&channel_response_desc=Payment+is+cancelled.&sub_merchant_list=";


    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(strMain, "&");



    while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
           String element = tokenizer.nextElement().toString();
           if(element.contains(CHANEL_RESPONSE_CODE)){
               String chanelReponseCodeValue[] = element.split("=");
               if(chanelReponseCodeValue.length>=2){
                   System.out.println(chanelReponseCodeValue[1]);
               }
              
           }
           if(element.contains(CHANEL_RESPONSE_DESC)){
               String chanelReponseDescValue[] = element.split("=");
               if(chanelReponseDescValue.length>=2) {
                   System.out.println(chanelReponseDescValue[1]);
               }
           }
           if(element.contains(REQUEST_TIME_STMP)){
               String  requestTimeStmp[] = element.split("=");
               if(requestTimeStmp.length>=2){
                   System.out.println(requestTimeStmp[1]);
               }

           }
           if(element.contains(MERCHANT_LIST)){
               String  merchantList[] = element.split("=");
               if(merchantList.length>=2) {
                   System.out.println(merchantList[1]);
               }
           }

    }

}
```

Comment: But how can I set the values in POJO fields. how can I access?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:   using your code.   Using split also  same Exception is there

Comment: remember there are fields like merchant list ,... who dont have value.

Comment: @Steve I updated answer. Just check the length of array which you get when splitting the string by "=" delimiter..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **Java8** with Jackson library way of doing it:

`Payment` Class:

```java
public class Payment {
    
    // You don't need @JsonProperty annotation if you have param name 
    // "requestTimestamp" in your URL or if you name the attribute here in POJO 
    // as "request_timestamp"

    @JsonProperty("request_timestamp")
    String requestTimestamp;
    
    @JsonProperty("channel_response_code")
    String channelResponseCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("channel_response_desc")
    String channelResponseDesc;
    
    @JsonProperty("sub_merchant_list")
    String subMerchantList;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String strMain = "request_timestamp=2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49&channel_response_code=0036&channel_response_desc=Payment+is+cancelled.&sub_merchant_list=1";

        Map<String, String> map = 
                Arrays.stream(URLDecoder.decode(strMain, "UTF-8").split("&"))
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                k -> ((String) k).split("=")[0], 
                                v -> ((String) v).split("=")[1]) // watch out for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
                       ); 
         
         // using Jackson library: import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         Payment pojo = mapper.convertValue(map, Payment.class);

        System.out.println(pojo.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```java
Payment [requestTimestamp=2020-08-11 15:11:49, channelResponseCode=0036, channelResponseDesc=Payment is cancelled., subMerchantList=1]
```

**Note:**

1. You can explore more about URL decoding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) (taken from Homilzio's answer)
2. You can exlpore `ObjectMapper` for more fine grained conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having issues with encoding, you can try:

```
 URLEncoder.encode(strMain, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

beefore.

More info in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
    class Payment {
        String requestTimestamp;
        String channelResponseCode;
        String channelResponseDesc;
        String subMerchantList;

        public static Payment parsePayment(String input) {
            return new Payment(input);
        }

        private Payment(String input) {
            String arrSplit[] = input.split("&");

            for (int i = 0; i < arrSplit.length; i++) {
                String[] keyValue = arrSplit[i].split("=");
                String key = null;
                if (keyValue.length > 0) {
                    key = keyValue[0];
                }
                String value = null;
                if (keyValue.length > 1) {
                    value = keyValue[1];
                }
                this.setPropertyValue(key, value);
            }
        }

        private void setPropertyValue(String key, String value) {
            System.out.println(String.format("'%s' = '%s'", key, value));

            switch (key) {
                case "request_timestamp":
                    this.requestTimestamp = value;
                    return;

                case "channel_response_code":
                    this.channelResponseCode = value;
                    return;

                case "channel_response_desc":
                    this.channelResponseDesc = value;
                    return;

                case "sub_merchant_list":
                    this.subMerchantList = value;
                    return;

                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Invalid key '%s'", key));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Payment{" +
                    "requestTimestamp='" + requestTimestamp + '\'' +
                    ", channelResponseCode='" + channelResponseCode + '\'' +
                    ", channelResponseDesc='" + channelResponseDesc + '\'' +
                    ", subMerchantList='" + subMerchantList + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    @Test
    void stackOverflow() {
        String strMain = "request_timestamp=2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49&channel_response_code=0036&channel_response_desc=Payment+is+cancelled.&sub_merchant_list=";
        Payment payment = Payment.parsePayment(strMain);
        System.out.println(payment.toString());
    }
```

The result:

```
'request_timestamp' = '2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49'
'channel_response_code' = '0036'
'channel_response_desc' = 'Payment+is+cancelled.'
'sub_merchant_list' = 'null'
Payment{requestTimestamp='2020-08-11+15%3A11%3A49', channelResponseCode='0036', channelResponseDesc='Payment+is+cancelled.', subMerchantList='null'}
```