# GET method in Java

Tags: java, php

In PHP, i've been able to use GET methods fairly easily.
For example:

```
www.test.com/test.php?id=29328932
```

And then using that information i can do this in PHP to get the value:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

In Java, i have a similar link:

```
www.test.com/Test?id=8127
```

However, i'm finding it a little difficult to figure out how to get the variable/value from the parameter. Is it possible to do this in Java?

Comment: What kind of HTTP server are you using in Java?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `$_GET` in PHP is used to retrieve GET parameters when processing your url parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are in a Servlet environment, you have a request object, you can try:

```
request.getParameter("id");
```

If you are parsing this from plain java, you could use something like what's described here:

[How to extract parameters from a given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902090/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-given-url)

Comment: Okay, so getting the id using getParameter inside the doGet(). That's further than i was before. Thanks :). However, now i'm trying to use this ID variable that i have inside a private function on the same page. How can i make it so that this variable can be used inside this function?

Answer (score 2):

Inside a servlet, use [`ServletRequest#getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        //use the parameter
    }
}
```

Inside JSP, use `param` variable from Expression Language:

```html
id: ${param['id']}
<br />
id: ${param.id}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much the same as the answer above. I have commented above on an issue leading from this one. If you could give me any pointers as to how to resolve it; would save myself a lot of time :). Thanks