# Java deparam the json object parameterized by Jquery.param() method

Tags: java, jquery

Is there a utility in java to de parameterize the object parameterized by  [Jquery param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method. I got the following code working for now( I can parse the returned map to a Json object).  Don't know how robust it will be. Is there a util in java just like [js one here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/)

```
public class Util {

/**
 * Deparameterize to original json form the query params coming from the jquery.param() method.
 * @param query the query string key value(array of values if same key repeated) pairs.
 * @return
 */
public static Map<String, Object> deParam(Map<String, String[]> query) {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<Map<String,Object>> toArray=new ArrayList<>();

    for (String key : query.keySet()) {
        //ex key $and[0][price][$lt]
        String value=query.get(key)[0];
        key = key.replace("]", "");

        String[] split = key.split("\\[");

        Map<String, Object> grandParent =null;
        Map<String, Object> parent =map;
        String parentName="root";
        Map<String, Object> child = null;
        String lastSkey=null;

        for (String skey : split) {
            Object me = parent.get(skey);
            if(skey.matches("[0-9]+")){
                //if array key
                toArray.add(parent);
                parent.put("parent",grandParent);
                parent.put("myName", parentName );
            }
            if (me == null) {
                child=new HashMap<>();
                parent.put(skey, child);
                grandParent=parent;
                parent=child;
                parentName=skey;
            } else {
                grandParent=parent;
                parent = (Map<String, Object>) me;
                parentName=skey;
            }
            lastSkey=skey;
        }
        if(value.matches("[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]+")){
            Double numVal=new Double(value);
            grandParent.put(lastSkey,numVal);
        }else {
            grandParent.put(lastSkey,value);
        }

    }

    for (Map<String, Object> arrayMap : toArray) {
        Map<String, Object> myParent = (Map<String, Object>) arrayMap.remove("parent");
        String myName = (String) arrayMap.remove("myName");
        if(myParent!=null&&myName!=null){
            myParent.put(myName, arrayMap.values());
        }else if(myName!=null && myName.equals("root")){
            map.put("list", arrayMap.values());
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide some input examples for the `Map<String, String[]> query` param.

Comment: Also the desired output based on the inputs. Examples of all possible kinds would be helpful. E.g. `{ width:1680, height:1050, test: [1,2,3] }` - param -> `width=1680&height=1050&test%5B%5D=1&test%5B%5D=2&test%5B%5D=3` - decodeURI -> `width=1680&height=1050&test[]=1&test[]=2&test[]=3`

Comment: Isn't this just standard URL parameter parsing?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902090/how-to-extract-parameters-from-a-given-url for example but there are *many* others.